In a bibliography hanging indentation, what is the appropriate indentation amount?
According to the Chicago Manual of Style, a bibliography entry should be set in a hanging indentation (where the first line is set flush left, and subsequent lines are "indented").
My question is: "indented" by how much? The style guide does not seem to be clear on that point.

Is it a tab amount – whatever that amount is for whatever the actual real typographic element tab is supposed to stand for?
Is it a fixed amount of half an inch, regardless of any other circumstances like font size, paper size, etc.?  (This seems to be the answer I get when I do an internet search.)
Or is it whatever length a normal paragraph indentation happens to be – which in MS Word coincides with the tab length and which coincidentally is half an inch, but which paragraph indentation might be different in other systems that might take into account the font size/style?

Any help would be appreciated.

The Chicago Manual of Style (2017) specifies in section 2.11:

For the purposes of the man­uscript, the typical default value for tabs or indents can normally be used (usually half an inch).

To translate that for you:

There is no prescribed depth of indentation.
You can indent your bibliography as far as you want.
It is absolutely fine to use the default value of your word processor.
Half an inch seems to be common.

This applies to manuscripts only. There is no rule for printed books or journals. If your paper is published, the depth of indentation will either be prescribed by the publisher and defined in a style guide that you have been given or the typesetter will take care of this and you don't have to worry about it.

Some typographical clarifications:

A tab, short for tabulator, is not a typographical unit or element at all. It does not exist in typography. Today, a tab is the virtual distance from the position of the cursor to the next tab stop in an electronic document. Since these tab stops can be arbitrarily defined, the tab distance does not correspond to any fixed physical distance. By default, in Microsoft Word, the first tab is set at half an inch.
The default indentation, for both first-line or hanging indents, is half an inch in a manuscript. The default indentation in print today is one quad or one em and therefore dependent on font size.
A default is not a norm. A book designer may choose any other indentation depth. In a manuscript, though, the default is usually the convention.

